Clarification on Algebraic Structures as Group Actions
I am preparing the initial lectures for a course on representation theory and aim to motivate the idea that "everything in mathematics is a 'group' action." To illustrate this, I plan to start by showing how various algebraic structures can be viewed as group actions. For instance:
Vector spaces can be seen as a field acting on an abelian group.
Modules are a more general example, where a ring acts on an abelian group.

However, I am struggling to fully understand how the axioms of vector spaces and modules translate into these interpretations as group actions. Could you please help clarify this? Additionally, if possible, I would appreciate examples of similar interpretations for other algebraic structures.
Finally, from a categorical perspective, is there a way to generalize these ideas further?
Thank you for your guidance.

Does this MSE post answer your question?
